# How to read/write nested structure to file c?

Tags: c

I want to store nested structs to a .dat file and read it once i need it in another file.

It says "Segmentation fault(core dumped) while reading the file.

How can i solve this???

these are the structures:

```
struct address {
    int code;
    char city[10];
};

struct student {
    char name[10];
    struct address *ads;
};
```

this is the code for write:

```
struct student *person;
    if((person = malloc(sizeof(*person))) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(person->name, "s1");
    if((person->ads = malloc(sizeof(*(person->ads)))) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate memory to address\n");
        free(person);
        return -1;
    }
    person->ads->code = 1;
    strcpy(person->ads->city, "mumbai");
    FILE *file;
    if((file = fopen("file.dat", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.dat\n");
        free(person->ads);
        free(person);
        return -1;
    }
    fwrite(&person, sizeof(*person), 1, file);
    if(fwrite) {
        printf("written\n");
    }else{
        printf("not written\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
```

this is code for read:

```
    struct student *person;
    FILE *file;
    if((file = fopen("file.dat", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file.dat\n");
        free(person);
        return -1;
    }
    fread(&person, sizeof(*person), 1, file);
    printf("cityname: %s\n", person->ads->city);
    fclose(file);
```

Comment: Please read up on "serialisation" and report how much that concept is what you want and how much it already answers your problem. The technical expressio shoudl allow you to make your question more to the point. But, hmm, the body of your question, in contrast to the title, just discusses a segfault... So maybe not.

Comment: (1) You need to allocate space for `person` (2) You need to read the data into the space you allocate, not the pointer itself.

Comment: You have only written `person`, not any of the things its pointers point to.

Comment: Without having looked too much at your code, a significant issue is passing `&person` to `fread()` and `fwrite()`. `person` is already a pointer, so you're passing a `struct student **`, and possibly overwriting other stuff. Also, there's no guarantee that the layout of the struct will be the same on a different platform.

Answer (score 1):

`struct address` is *not* "nested" in `struct student`; `struct student` contains a *pointer*, not a nested structure.

Pointers cannot be meaningfully written with `write`: you can do it but the result is only meaningful during the lifetime of the object pointed at, and only in the process in which the object exists. The point of writing data to an external file is usually to allow its use in the indefinite future and in another process, neither of which are true for a pointer.

If you want to write an object like `struct address` to persistent storage, you will have to *serialise* the data: that is, convert it to a format in which multiple objects can be written with a clear indication of the relationship between them. You'll find many serialisation frameworks with a little research into the term, but this case might be simple enough for a direct implementation. Undoubtedly that's the point of this homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to rici's excellent answer, I would encourage you to look into data serialization frameworks. Writing serialization code by hand is tedious and error-prone, and even more so once you start extending the file format, which is likely to happen at some point. There are several useful ones out there, such as [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/), [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) or [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)